# Determine tile size for matrix multiplication with AVX

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication, avx

I wrote the code below for tiled matrix multiplication with AVX.

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void fill(double *mat, int n) {
  register int i;
  register int j;
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      mat[i * n + j] = (double) (i * n + j);
    }
  }
}

void blocked_mmul_avx(double *A, double *B, double *C, int n) {
  register int row, block, chunk, sub_chunk;
  int block_size = 4;

  for (row = 0; row < n; row++)
    for (block = 0; block < n; block += block_size) {
      register __m256d c0 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
      for (chunk = 0; chunk < n; chunk += block_size) {
        for (sub_chunk = 0; sub_chunk < block_size; sub_chunk++) {
          register __m256d a = _mm256_broadcast_sd(
              &A[row * n + chunk + sub_chunk]);
          register __m256d b = _mm256_loadu_pd(
              &B[chunk * n + sub_chunk * n + block]);
          c0 += a * b;
        }
      }
      _mm256_storeu_pd(&C[row * n + block], c0);
    }
}

int main() {
  int n = 4096; //n = 512, 1024, 2048, 4096

  double *A;
  double *B;
  double *C;

  A = (double*) malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));
  B = (double*) malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));
  C = (double*) malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));

  srand(0);
  fill(A, n);  // it is a function to load A and B with random numbers
  fill(B, n);

  printf("n = %d\n\n", n);
  clock_t t0 = clock();
  blocked_mmul_avx(A, B, C, n);
  clock_t t1 = clock();
  printf("Execution Time = %0.3f s \n\n", (float) (t1 - t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

  free(A);
  free(B);
  free(C);
  return 0;
}
```

If I set size of the block to 4, the code works correctly. But if I increase it to 16, 1/4 of entries of output matrix is correct. I don't know why this is happening??
I checked and there are 16 YMM registers so I think block size can be increased to 16. But my experiment shows the otherwise.
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You question talks about setting “size of the block to 4,” but you do not show what that means in the code. The only `block` in the code is used in a `for` loop where it has multiple values over time, not a single value of 4. Edit the question to provide a [mre] showing the code that does not work. Note that a [mre] includes **everything** a reader needs to reproduce the problem with no additions or insertions: A complete program, all the input data, and commands to build and execute. But it should be **minimal**, a program made as small as it can be made while still demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I edited the code to show what I mean by block size. also I wrote the code based on https://coffeebeforearch.github.io/assets/mmul/blocked_chunk.png but I changed it for AVX. so when block size is four it means that 4 elements of first matrix and 4*4 block of second matrix are chosen to build four entries of output matrix.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thanks for your comment. I posted it.